# follow up on: Can ような mean "To make"?

Tags: meaning, verbs

a follow up on: [Can ような mean "To make"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60189/can-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%aa-mean-to-make)

> X は仰け反り、聞いてるこちらが悲しくなる**ような**悲鳴を上げた。

X shrieked in a way that made me become sorrowful

> Person talking to the speaker was singing before
>
> あの惚れ惚れする**ような**歌声を聞いていたためか、ひどく棒読みに聞こえるのは。

I heard her voice as extremely monotone, maybe because i had already heard her singing voice that enchanted me (made me enchanted?)

> あはは、と少女はおどけて笑う。意識しているのかどうかは不明だが、俺のいたたまれない緊張がほぐれる**ような**優しい笑みだった。

It was unclear whether she(I?) realized it or not , but it was a smile that made my unendurable tension relax.

I feel this usage is much more explicit for the first example, does also apply to the other two examples?

Thank you

Comment: Vような maybe, but ような by itself won't produce a verb.

Answer (score 1):

> Can ような mean “To make”?

No.

よう(な) literally means something like "form, way, shape". And it indicates that something **is like** something in this case.

> あの惚れ惚れするような歌声 = That singing voice like one we would be charmed by (literally)

The action marked by ような isn't actually executed.

But of course, when translating, you could translate it by "to make" even though in my opinion it's not 100% accurate, there isn't a universal translation for everything.

Comment: would you say the 2nd and 3rd examples are like [文句を言いたくなるような人 (ambiguous) a troublesome person who deserves complaints / a person who wants to complain] from the link?

Comment: @charu Yes, the ような  is the same